# Execute effect if component is displayed only

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a panel that i want to execute a hide effect on it if it's shown only, and if it's hidden, the effect shouldn't work.

```
 <h:outputLink id="open_link" value="#" styleClass="underline">
            Click To Open   

<p:effect for="blank_panel" type="blind" event="click" speed="2000">
        <f:param name="mode" value="'hide'" />
</p:effect>

<p:effect type="blind" event="click" for="display_tabs" delay="1000">
    <f:param name="mode" value="'show'" />
</p:effect>

</h:outputLink>

    <h:panelGroup id="blank_panel" layout="block">

    </h:panelGroup>
```

I want when clicking on the link for the second time (blank_panel is hidden in this case)
the effect for the blank_panel is not executed

```
     <!-- executed only if the blank_panel is shown -->
     <p:effect for="blank_panel" type="blind" event="click" speed="2000">
        <f:param name="mode" value="'hide'" />
</p:effect>
```

Comment: Since you want to use `p:effect` of primefaces I think you should *play* with two `<h:outputLink` with their visibility , pressing one should hide it and show the second `<h:outputLink` and vice versa...

Comment: @Daniel, is there's a way to check component style ? like rendered="#{blank_panel.style.display=='block'}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INMO you really better use jQuery effects, but...

Since you want to use p:effect of primefaces I think you should play with two `<h:outputLink` with their visibility , pressing one should hide it and show the second `<h:outputLink` and vice versa...

```
 <h:outputLink id="open_link" 
    onclick="$('#open_link').hide();$('#open_link2').show();" value="#" 
    styleClass="underline">
            Click To Open   
    <p:effect....
    <p:effect....
 </h:outputLink>


 <h:outputLink id="open_link2"
    onclick="$('#open_link2').hide();$('#open_link').show();" value="#" 
    styleClass="underline">
            Click To Open   
    <p:effect...
 </h:outputLink>
```

Not sure about the ids... (if you don't use prependId="false" or etc...)